# all value in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a grid view table populated using a stored procedure. The grid view table loads and works fine. The problem I am having is how to get all the values in a particular column.

So far, I can only get the value of the 1 column and cell. I need all the values in that column for each row. Numbers of value varies depending on the parameters user set.

code is in c#. This gets me the first column, first row.

```
 gridviewID.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            gridviewID.DataBind();
            TxBx.Text = gridviewID.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for each loop to get all the rows within the grid view.

```
IList<string> parameters = new List<string>();
foreach (GridViewRow row in AdminSearchGridView.Rows)
{
  parameters.Add(row.Cells[0].Text);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Problem now is to take all the values and use it as a parameter for another stored procedure. Thank you @Kiran Hegde

Comment: What parameters do you pass to the stored procedure? GridView can have any number of rows, how do you pass these values?

Comment: I am using values from a dropdownlist (int), textbox(VarChar), and listbox(int){selectvalue} which then populate the gridview. I need all the value from the column to be used as a parameter for the other stored procedure which will initiate in a database table.

Comment: I still dont know how do you pass all these values to stored procedure. But I have changed the code above, which stores all the values in a list, which can be reused for further process